# How to make all the buttons in a form unpressable?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm programming a card game.
I use an async method and an await Task.Delay() code to stop the code from continuing so that the user will see that he made a mistake or succeeded  instead of instantly the cards flipping back. 
but while the code itself stops. the user still can press the buttons and it interrupts the code.
how do i make the buttons unpressable while the code is on delay ?

```
private async void Cards(ButtonBase Card1,int Val)
    {
        Card1.Text = Card1.Name;
        count++;
        if (count == 2){
            val2 = Val;
            if (val1 == val2 && PrevCard != Card1)
            {

                await Task.Delay(2000);                    
                Card1.Enabled = false;
                PrevCard.Enabled = false;                    
                Card1.Text = "Correct";
                PrevCard.Text = "Correct";
                count = 0;
                val1 = 0;
                val2 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                Card1.Text = "";
                PrevCard.Text = "";                 
                count = 0;
                val1 = 0;
                val2 = 0;

            }
            PrevCard = null;
        }
        else
        {
            val1 = Val;
            PrevCard = Card1;
        }                  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little `deactivateButtons()` method would do it:

```
        private void deactivateButtons()
        {
            foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if(c is Button)
                { c.Enabled = false; }
            }
        }
```

Calling this method before you execute your code and another method `activateButtons()` after finishing your code should do it. I think you can write the second method on your own ;-)

Comment: It's great Thank you very much